# jQuery right place to put NOT in selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jquery line

```
$('[genre*="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').fadeOut('fast');
```

It fadeouts the elements with genre whose value contains this element's id's value.

However what i want to achieve is to fadeout the remaining elements, not the ones that match. So something like this:

```
$('[genre*="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]:not').fadeOut('fast');
```

Where is the right place to put the "not".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work. I wrote the code here, but the idea is to select all elements having 'genre' attribute and check if the id value is not contained in this attribute. If not so, fade out that element.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('[genre]').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).attr('genre').search(id))
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Edit: By the way, you are searching for elements that have the genre attribute and having a value on this attirubte which contains some keyword. If you use not operator on this selector you end up with all elements except those, which ends up in almost all the elements in the document. To my knowledge there is not a selector in jQuery that is like 'having "some" attribute and value not containing "this value"'.

Comment: Thanks but this code fadeouts the elements with the same genre.. As it did with this code $('[genre*="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').fadeOut('fast');

Comment: Your code seems correct but when I removed the ! it worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

ou have to place it in front of the selector

```
$(':not([genre*="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"])').fadeOut('fast');
```

To get more information and samples, please check the official reference for [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

**EDIT**

That selector in particular would cause undesired effects as it is. You could fix it with something like this

```
$('[genre]').filter(':not([genre*="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"])').fadeOut('fast');​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. But everything fade outs in this case. Maybe there is some logic error in the original line..

Comment: This line matches all DOM elements except those which include id in the genre attribute. This means, that <body> will also be included.